# How can I automate FTP downloads based on date without bi-directional syncing?

Tags: ftp

I have a particular FTP-related situation that I'm having trouble finding a solution for.

I need an FTP download/syncing application that can operate within the following parameters:

- It must run under Windows (installing Python to be able to run a script or some such thing is an acceptable solution).
- It must be able to ignore files before a certain date (I want to start downloading new files, not *all* the files that exist in this very large FTP directory).
- I don't want bi-directional syncing (e.g. I don't want changes I make to the local files and directory structure to change the remote FTP server, the FTP server needs to be left completely alone).
- Automating it in some fashion would be ideal.

What would you guys suggest? The solutions I'm turning up are all missing the mark in some fashion (e.g. they have bi-directional syncing or they have no way of starting the syncing today instead of trying to pull down the entire directory).

Comment: Having have bi-directional syncing should not be a problem, as long as you can turn that off. (E.g. with rsync).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably coming too late for you but I'll answer for anyone else who stumbles across this in their search for something similar.

LFTP's mirror function includes a --newer-than= function.

For files newer than last week:

```
--newer-than=now-7days
```

For files newer than a specified date:

```
--newer-than=2015-02-03
```

Here's an example:

```
lftp -p <port> -u <login>,<password> sftp://<host>
set mirror:use-pget-n 5
mirror -L -c -P5 --newer-than=now-7days <remote_dir> <local_dir>
```